# Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement llama-index-finetuning-cross-encoders

Tags: pytorch, large-language-model, llama-index, fine-tuning

I'm trying to run this Llama Index [How to Finetune a cross-encoder using LLamaIndex](https://docs.llamaindex.ai/en/stable/examples/finetuning/cross_encoder_finetuning/cross_encoder_finetuning.html).
And, I cannot install `llama-index-finetuning-cross-encoders` package.

I tried this code

```
%pip install llama-index-finetuning-cross-encoders
```

And, I cannot install `llama-index-finetuning-cross-encoders` package with this Error comment.

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement llama-index-finetuning-cross-encoders (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for llama-index-finetuning-cross-encoders
```

How can I install this package? :)